# File not getting copied in perl

Tags: perl, unix, file-io

File "/root/actual" is not getting over written with content of "/root/temp" via perl script. If manually edited "/root/actual" is getting modified.

```
copy("/root/actual","/root/temp") or die "Copy failed: $!";


open(FILE, "</root/temp") || die "File not found";
my @lines = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

my @newlines;
foreach(@lines) {
   $_ =~ s/$aref1[0]/$profile_name/;
   push(@newlines,$_);
}

open(FILE, ">/root/actual") || die "File not found";
print FILE @newlines;
close(FILE);
```

Comment: Is that `die "File not found"` command executing? Or, does the script run, but nothing happens?

Comment: Is this your **entire** script? Where is `@aref1` getting set? Where is the `use File::Copy;`?

Comment: used File::Copy also. No Die command is not getting executed.

Comment: Can you post your whole script? That would be very helpful. You should alway use `use warnings;` and `use strict;` in your Perl programs. You also need to read up on more modern syntax too. Also, let us know of any output your script produces. We need a bit more explanation than "It's not working".

Answer (score 1):

> File "/root/actual" is not getting over written with content of "/root/temp" via perl script. If manually edited "/root/actual" is getting modified.

Do you mean that `/root/temp` isn't being replaced by `/root/actual`? Or is `/root/temp` being modified as you wish, but it's not copying over `/root/acutual` at the end of your program?

I suggest that you read up on modern Perl programming practices. You need to have `use warnings;` and `use strict;` in your program. In fact, many people on this forum won't bother answering Perl questions unless `use strict;` and `use warnings;` are used.

Where is `$aref1[0]` coming from? I don't see `@aref1` declared anywhere in your program. Or, for that matter `$profile_name`.

If you're reading in the entire file into a regular expression, there's no reason to copy it over to a temporary file first.

I rewrote what you had in a more modern syntax:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use constant {
    FILE_NAME => 'test.txt',
};

my $profile_name = "bar";                #Taking a guess
my @aref1 = qw(foo ??? ??? ???);         #Taking a guess

open my $input_fh, "<", FILE_NAME;
my @lines = <$input_fh>;
close $input_fh;

for my $line ( @lines ) {
    $line =~ s/$aref1[0]/$profile_name/;
}

open my $output_fh, ">", FILE_NAME;
print ${output_fh} @lines;
close $output_fh;
```

This works.

#### Notes:

1. `use autodie;` means you don't have to check whether files opened.
2. When I use a `for` loop, I can do *inplace* replacing in an array. Each item is a pointer to that entry in the array.
3. No need for `copy` or a temporary file since you're replacing the original file anyway.
4. I didn't use it here since you didn't, but `map { s/$aref1[0]/$profile_name/ } @lines;` can replace that `for` loop. See [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).